# How to move focus on a textbox in a table which is in one table cell to another table cell using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one row in a table. In that row are 8 columns. In that column I have one select2 one date picker and select2. I need to set focus from a datepicker, which is in one table cell to a select2 which is another table cell by pressing the enter key.

Comment: Whenever you are asking any question please consider adding code so that people can suggest you the changes.

Answer (score 1):

detect which key is pressed using **event.which** for enter key 13 is keycode.on key press we can check is enter key pressed and if enter key pressed its move focus to select2 field

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sel_field").select2();
  $(document).on('keypress', '#date_val', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      $("#sel_field").focus();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="date_val" id="date_val"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="sel_field" id="sel_field" style="width:200px">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```